# Facebook C# SDK + Events Attending

Tags: c#, facebook

I am trying to join a event through FB api like this but it gives me an error:

```
Parameter count mismatch.
```

upon hitting the line:

```
JsonObject result = facebookClient.Post("/" + eventid + "/attending") as JsonObject;
```

I have check that the access token and event id is in place. Can someone help. Thanks.

```
if (Session["FBAcctoken_Event"] != null)
            {
                var accessTok = Session["FBAcctoken_Event"].ToString();
                var eventid = hdnEventId.Value;
                eventid = eventid.Substring(11, eventid.Length - 11);
                FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessTok);

                JsonObject result = facebookClient.Post("/" + eventid + "/attending") as JsonObject;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
Dictionary<string,object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string,object>();
fbParams[access_token] = accessTok;         
JsonObject result = facebookClient.Post("/" + eventid + "/attending", fbParams) as JsonObject;
```